# What are the allowed thicknesses of a tennis ball shell?

Tags: rules, equipment, tennis, atp, wta

What are the allowed thicknesses of the shell of a tennis ball? I know the external diameter, but I'm interested in what thickness is allowed for the shell itself. I don't have a ball at hand to cut open...

(If there's a difference between e.g. ATP and WTA regulations, please mention both).

Comment: About [3 mm](http://www.physics.usyd.edu.au/~cross/PUBLICATIONS/7.%20BallsDynamicTests.PDF)...

Comment: Welcome. This is not a constructive question. Perhaps enlightening us as to why this is important to you would help.

Comment: I've tried to reformulate this into a "rules and regulations" question rather than an off-hand request for information. I'm not saying it's a great question, but I think it now counts as on-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard thickness of a pressurized tennis ball shell (eg, the tennis ball is intact and fresh removed from its airtight container) is about [3 mm](http://www.physics.usyd.edu.au/~cross/PUBLICATIONS/7.%20BallsDynamicTests.PDF).

The standard thickness of an unpressurized tennis ball shell (eg, if a tennis ball is cut open) is about [4 - 4.5 mm](http://www.physics.usyd.edu.au/~cross/PUBLICATIONS/7.%20BallsDynamicTests.PDF).

The US Patent for a [tennis ball](https://www.google.com/patents/US4739989) states that "the wall thickness of the shell is between 1.2 and 2.8 millimeters."

The ATP and WTA both reference the [ITF's Appendix I](http://www.itftennis.com/media/220771/220771.pdf) with respect to tennis ball measurements. Thickness of the shell is not mentioned.